# Google App Engine Local datastore appends ? to persisted bytes

Tags: google-app-engine

After storing blob (byte[]) to Google App Engine datastore, I get a  '?' appended to my data after same data fetching from Datastore.

I have an idea, that this has to do with encoding, Since I am not sure what GAE default encoding is,  so I tried several Charsets and I get different result, I thought if I share this, I could get more light to the issue.

In my DBHelper class (Util to save and get data), 
When I initially persisted data with:

```
Entity resultEntity = new Entity("Entity");
resultEntity.setProperty("HtmlResult", new Blob(str.getBytes()))
```

I get a '?' appended to the end of my result (data fetched from Local datastore)

After changing my code to below :

resultEntity.setProperty("HtmlResult", new Blob(str.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))));

Then I get �� appended to the result.

Also, I think when I used `ISO-8859-1`, I had � . Sorry for  not been sure but I had to deploy to GAE everytime before I can test.

This question is related to [Datastore in Hosted GAE- Google app engine appends '?' character during data retrieval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10464614/datastore-in-hosted-gae-google-app-engine-appends-character-during-data-ret) but not directly.

Please kindly give your suggestions.

FY: I also tried

```
<env-variables>
 <env-var name="DEFAULT_ENCODING" value="UTF-8" />
</env-variables>
```

**Please note that I do not have this problem on my local machine, only when I deploy and test my app on Google app engine.**

Answer (score 0):

This will help : http://blog.notdot.net/2010/07/Getting-unicode-right-in-Python